# Chrome extension installer executable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there ANY way to make an executable that installs a Chrome Extension without putting that extension in the store? Or at least from private collection (so it wouldn't be available for others)?

** Changing Chrome to DEV version or Canarian is not a solution **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no, at least not on Windows.

The [blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) is pretty unambiguous:

> [...] starting in January on the Windows stable and beta channels, we’ll require all extensions to be hosted in the Chrome Web Store.

You can publish an item to Chrome Web Store as "unlisted" and then use the [standard procedure](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry) to install it programmatically. This will limit exposure of your extension, but won't really prevent people from getting a link to install it (anyone with an installed version can find the web store listing by extension ID and can share it).

If you want to make a truly private extension, you can add server-side license checks. But be aware that no matter the distribution channel, they can be bypassed, since the source code is exposed in a convenient debugger anyway. On the plus side, the same hoops you have to jump through will limit damage from any "cracked" versions.

Comment: In addition to "unlisted" and "public", there is also "private", which allows one to publish to a Google group or a list of testers (this requires the users of the extension to log in using their Google account in order to install the extension).

Comment: @RobW True. But are there any client-side protections on the extension code? What stops a user from copying the extension folder, making small changes to the manifest, and then republishing it as public (in principle)?

Comment: Nothing besides a terms of use and a good lawyer, but then we get into DRM and piracy, which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Even if you have an executable that installs an extension there is nothing stopping a user from copying it and publishing to the CWS.

Comment: So the only way to protect your extension is to use some obfuscator?